# Browser to browser VoIP calling using SIP?

Tags: python, browser, sip, phone-call, pjsip

I am trying to call from `one browser to another browser`.

**What I have done:**

1. I set up my `asterisk serve`r just like `getonsip.com`
2. I wrote a `client` using `pjsua python binding` which acts as a `server`

**Here is the situation:**

1. I can call from my browser ( My browser is on the same machine on which pjsua client is running) to my sip client on my android phone.
2. I am not able to do same  from the browser from another machine.
3. What should I do for making a browser to browser call happen?
4. Does streaming and flash required for doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to say that the software you have written is able to make calls but not receive them? Post the relevant part of your client code where you listen for incoming calls and we might be able to help.

Comment: Here is the senario: I have pjsua running on my local machine. I have written a web client which can call to my android sip client when I hit a particular url. Now I open another browser on my machine and I registerd my self with "foo" account. Now "bar" is already registered on another browser. I can call to android sip from "foo" and "bar" but not able to call from "bar" to "foo" or "foo" to "bar" I am updating my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do browser-to-browser calls with SIP at least not without a lot of plugin magic. The first problem is that by default SIP uses UDP port 5060, the browser sandbox won't let you communicate on that port so you'd need a plugin (Flash, Silverlight, Java Applet etc.). Once you've overcome the SIP side, and dealt with the NAT headaches along the way, you'd then need to work out how to get the browser to process the RTP media stream. That would mean more plugins.

There is actually an upcoming standard that deals with exactly what you are after, see [RTC-WEB](http://rtc-web.alvestrand.com/). While you're waiting for that you could try and get by with [phono](http://phono.com/) which is a javascript/flash component from Tropo that supports browser based calling but with the caveat being the call will traverse Tropo's SIP servers.

Comment: It's not my link but irrespective it's working for me. It's simply a site with some info on the protocol so if it doesn't work for you just Google around.

Comment: But why my browser need to concern about port 5060 because my browser will talk to my pjsua server (client for sip) and the pjsua server will talk to sip over port 5060

Comment: You'll only be able to connect to port 5060 from a browser using a plugin. So yes you could write a browser-to-browser softphone using Java or similar but you'd effectively be circumventing the browser so why not skip the browser in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible **now**, since [WebRTC](http://webrtc.org) finally became standard and there are already implementations in both browsers and SIP server

- [Asterisk 11 is officially support WebRTC](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support)
- Google Chrome has built-in WebRTC support since version 23

See this tutorial for more details http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/